# Regex error when trying to print all overlapping matches

Tags: python

I've looked at several examples of how to achieve overlapping matching. The answer seemed to be **lookahead assertions**, so I used that but am getting an error (I'm weak at regular expressions, so please excuse silly mistakes!).

The problem: Find all overlapping matches of the string `_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#` (that's 16 pairs) in the string `#__#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#__#__#_________####_#_##__`. I can see that there are at least two matches.

Here's the code I tried:

```
import re
pattern = r'?=((_#){16})'
row='#__#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#_#__#__#_________####_#_##__'
re.finditer(pattern, row)
```

Which throws an exception saying "Nothing to repeat". Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Funny, but I managed to find it myself. I'm missing parenthesis around the lookahead expression! It has to be `(?=...)` instead of `?=...`